# Unix system calls : read/write and the buffer

Tags: c, pointers, unix, operating-system, buffer

I am writing a pretty simple script .

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main(){
        int pipefd[2];
        pid_t c;
        int value[2];
        c = fork();
        if(c<0){
                perror("in fork");
                exit(1);
        }
        if(c==0){
                printf("i am the child\n");
                int buf[2];
                buf[0]=3;
                buf[1]=0;
                write(pipefd[1], buf, 4);
                write(pipefd[1],buf+1,4);
                close(pipefd[1]);
                exit(0);
        }
          if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {      /*UPDATE */
                        perror("pipe");   
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
          }

        read(pipefd[0], value, 4);
        read(pipefd[0], value+1, 4);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        printf("%d %d\n", value[0], value[1]);
        exit(0);
}
```

What I intend to do is to achieve:

**value[0] = buf[0];
value[1] = buf[1];**

( and print those of course).

But all I get as a result is :

```
-1299582208 32766
i am the child
```

Because, I have ints, I assumed that each will hold 4 bytes. And I think that for an int array each element will holds 4 bytes. But clearly I am missing something. Any help?

Comment: You're also assuming everything works like you expect.  Check the return value from your `read()` and `write()` calls.

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: @EOF: C 2018 6.3.2.1 2 makes using the value of an indeterminate object undefined behavior only if it could have been declared `register`. Arrays cannot be declared `register`. So using `value[0]` or `value[1]` does not have undefined behavior.

Comment: You use `int pipefd[2];` so I assume you want to communicate with pipes. So where is the `pipe` syscall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in my top comment: *Where is the `pipe` syscall?*

Without it, the `write` and `read` calls will probably fail because `pipefd` has random values.

So, the parent will never have `value` filled in correctly.

Because these [unitialized] values are on the stack, they will have random values, which is what you're seeing.

This is UB [undefined behavior].

Different systems/compilers may manipulate the stack differently, which is why you see *different* [yet still random] results on different configurations.

To fix, add the following *above* your `fork` call:

```
pipe(pipefd);
```

I downloaded, built, and ran your program. Before I added the fix, I got random values. After applying the fix, I get `3 0` as the output, which is what you expected/wanted.

*Note:* As others have mentioned, you could check the return codes for `read` and `write`. If you had, they might return `-1` and put an error code in `errno` that would have helped you debug the issue.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I updated my code but it still won't work as I wish, if you like you can give it a look

Comment: I'm away from my desktop at the moment, but in the meantime, what behavior do you want that is different from what I got (e.g. `3 0`)? For what inputs/outputs?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple fix would be to put a `sleep(1)` call right above your `read()` calls - obviously this isn't a great solution.

An important early lesson in multi process programming and communications is "race conditions". Your fork'd child is executing before the parent, it seems. I bet if you ran this 20 times, you might get X number of times where it does what you want!

You cannot guarantee the order of execution. So a sleep(1) will suffice until you learn more advanced techniques on resource locking (mutexes, semaphores).

Comment: There are _no_ race conditions here. See my top comment and answer

Comment: Yeah. You're right. I'm not sure what happened to my brain!